# How to assign weights to strings in WHERE clause?

Tags: teradata

The table is

```
 id  col1    col2  
 1   former  good  
 2   future  fair
 3   now     bad
 4   former  good
    .............
```

**GOAL : I need to SELECT only those rows that have a cumulative score higher than 0.8**

1) If col1 = 'former' THEN the row gets 0.2 points, if 'now' THEN '0.7' , if 'future' THEN 0.3

2) If col2 = 'good' THEN the row gets 0.8 points, if 'bad' THEN '0.1' , if 'fair' THEN 0.5

---

Therefore I need to I need to assign numeric values in the WHERE clause. I want to avoid changing values in the SELECT because I need the user to be able to see the labels ('good', 'now' etc) but not numbers.

How can I do this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a CASE to assign a weight based on your logic:

```
WHERE 
   CASE col1 
      WHEN 'former' THEN 0.2
      WHEN 'now'    THEN 0.7
      WHEN 'future' THEN 0.3
      ELSE 0
   END +
   CASE col2 
      WHEN 'good' THEN 0.8 
      WHEN 'bad'  THEN 0.1
      WHEN 'fair' THEN 0.5
      ELSE 0
   END > 0.8
```

Comment: Thank you. But why do I get an error: `string character failed conversion to numeric val ...`

Comment: `A character string failed conversion to a numeric value` . Should I introduce a new variable ?

Comment: This will work as-is with your example data. It must be something else in your query. Could you show what you tried?

Comment: I had to convert to varchar. Ones i did i worked i dont know why Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where col1 + col2 > 0.8
```

But provide us the real structure of the table.

Comment: col1 and col2 are `varchar`